# Loop of missing data by year

Tags: r, loops

I need to run a loop for my dataset, ds. the dim of ds is 4000, 11. Each country of the world of represented. And each country has data from 1970 to 1999.

The data set has missing data amongst its 8 rows. I need to run a loop that calculates how much missing data there is PER year. the year is in df$year.

I am pretty sure the years (1970, 1971, 1972...) are numeric values.

This is my current code

```
missingds<-c()
for (i in 1:length(ds)){
    missingds[names(ds)[i]]<-sum(is.na(ds[i]))/4000
}
```

This gives me the proportion of missing data per variable of ds. I just cannot figure out how to get it report the proportion of all the variables per year.

I do have an indicator variable ds$missing which reports 1 if there is an NA in any of the columns of that row and 0 if not.

[A picture of ds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dE4f9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

To count number of `NA` values in each column using dplyr you can do :

```
library(dplyr)

result <- data %>%
            group_by(Year) %>%
            summarise(across(gdp_growth:polity, ~sum(is.na(.))))
```

In base R you can use `aggregate` :

```
aggregate(cbind(gdp_growth, gdp_per_capita, inf_mort, pop_density, polity)~year, 
          data, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
```

Replace `sum` with `mean` if you want to count the proportions of `NA` value in each `year`.

Comment: How about without using dplyr?

Comment: @869picardy Updated the answer with base R option. BTW, it is helpful if you post your data in a reproducible format instead of screenshot. We cannot copy data from the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(is.na(x))),
    by = Year, .SDcols = gdp_growth:polity]
```